# How to get the direct link to a facebook iFrame url?

Tags: facebook, iframe

I have a app which url is like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/Foo/app_123456789
```

this app is running in a iframe and loading some urls of my server. At the start the user see a page like[1]:

```
www.foo.com/index.php
```

but in the app you also get pages like[2]:

```
https://foo.com/foo1/test/Tab/New/12345-6789
```

now the question:
is it possible to get a link which start with `facebook.com/...` and directly lead you to the [2] url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can add an extra variable to your URL like so:

```
https://www.facebook.com/Foo/app_123456789?app_data=any_string_here
```

Facebook will then send whatever inside the [`app_data` variable](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) to your iframe inside the `singed_request`. So all you have to do is to check for its presence (and value) and redirect the user accordingly.

Comment: But I need to know exactly how to add the app_data that the iframe automatically will be opened

Comment: You mean for your *other* page to automatically open? this is not possible you **have** to handle this yourself. Try reading the `signed_request` with and without the `app_data` parameter to better understand the concept.

Comment: OK so it is only possible to add normal parameters like I'd=2 but not the url

Comment: exactly you are whatever parameter you want and check it when the iframe is loaded and then redirect to the related page